# AWS ELB Latency issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-rds

I have two c3.2xlarge EC2 machines with Ubuntu environment both in us-west-2a AZ. Both contains same code with mySQL database from AWS RDS (db.r3.2xlarge). Both instances are added to an ELB. Both has one cron scheduled that runs twice in a day.

ELB has been configured to raise the alarm once the threshold crosses 5.0. The CPU utilization of both the instances are by average 30 - 50. At peak hours hits 100% for a minute or two and then returns to normal. But ELB constantly raises alarm thrice a day. At this time, both instances has

```
CPU     - ~50%
Memory  - total - 14979
          used  - ~6000
          free  - ~9000
RDS CPU - ~30%
          Connections - 200 to 300 /5,000
```

According to this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-latency-troubleshooting/ I could find nothing wrong with the instances. But still latency hits the peak and both instance fails to respond.

Till now, I am just removing one of the instance from the load balancer, restart the apache and then load it back and do the same for other instance. This does the job perfectly alright and the instances and ELB works good for next 6-10 hours. But this is not acceptable since, every day twice or thrice one has to take care of the server, needs it to restart.

I need to know, if there is anything wrong or any steps to be taken to resolve this problem.

[image: Latency]

Answer (score 0):

from your question: it's not clear what the ELB alarm is monitoring. 5.0 500s?

What I guess happens is that when the CPU is spiking to 100% the service that sits behind the load balancer is slow to respond / not responding. Alert is triggered.

Even worse, if just one of the instances fails (assume cron jobs don't run at the same time) the ELB will take the instance out of service and the other instance will take all of the traffic. If one instance cannot take all of the traffic, what this means is that you will have the 2nd instance fails + trigger the alert also.

Why do you need to run the cron job on the same machine as the service? Is moving this off these machines an option? Also: is increasing the ELB  health check timeouts an option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply... 1. ELB alarm - 5000s | 2. CPU utilization of both instance is by average 50% when alarm alerts | 3. I think cron is scheduled to run only twice and it doesn't take much resource, since some 10-20 update queries and some file write operations in it that gets completed in less than 10s. I mentioned that to ensure that no cron is running other than this.

Comment: what are the 500s that you are receiving? (error?) is this the application that is failing here? do you have logs setup for the load balancer and your application that runs on the EC2 instances?

Comment: 5000s is the Average Latency (Milliseconds). Yes application runs in EC2 instance - c3.2xlarge

Comment: got it. so one request takes more than 5000s? how is the load balancer configured? do you have logs?

Comment: Yes, as the definition from AWS website says. And am not clear with your question - "load balancer configuration" yes it is configured and it is serving the best. Once apache server is restarted, both instances work as it should. | Added image to the question